# sIFR will not display

Tags: sifr

My test page:
http://nyttravelshow.o3worlddev.com/trunk/

My Js
trunk/js/sifr_config.js

My CSS
trunk/css/sifr.css

any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 404's on the SWF files needed for the sIFR, so that would be the first thing to look into.